# Alamofire responseObject cannot use for Bool response

Tags: swift3, alamofire

Api response only boolean like "true" or "false", Alamofire responseObject couldn't use. 
I am using AlamofireObjectMapper 4.0 and Swift 3.0

Could you suggest me how should I do?

Currently I am calling api like that:

```
Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<TestDto>) in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            success(response.result.value!)
            break

        case .failure(_):
            failure(response.result.error!)
            break
        }
    }
```

Api response is only true or false.

Comment: Got it using Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers).responseJSON{ (response: Any) in
            
            print(response)
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the responseJSON as below,

```
Alamofire.request(API_URL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers : headers).responseJSON{ (response: Any) in print(response) }
```